# Loop through Rounds while calling for New user Selection after each round Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a Rock Paper Scissors game, and I am stuck on a for concepts. I want the user to select the amount of rounds they want through a textbox. Each time the user clicks on a specific image (rock, paper, or scissors) the computer will randomly compile and this will select and image for the computer. Both user and computer chosen images will display in the center of the page in the red and blue squares. I want this to run in a loop until all rounds are complete and then decide an ultimate winner. I am getting lost on how I will make my Loop call for the function where I am having the user select an image, and do this until cpu or user wins. All I am looking for is a bit of guidance as to why I can't figure out how to call for the users selection and then chose a user selection, and repeat this process to completion.

```js
function startGame() {
  document.getElementById("gameInfo").style.display = "contents";
}

function clearGame() {
  document.getElementById("gameInfo").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("cpu").src = "";
  document.getElementById("user").src = "";
  document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("userDisplay").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("userName").value = "";
}

function displayName() {
  var txtName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  document.getElementById("userDisplay").innerHTML = txtName;
}

/*function roundNumber(input) {
    var total = document.getElementById("roundChoice").value;
    //compSelection(total.value);
    console.log(total);
}*/

function userPick(input) {
  document.getElementById("user").src = input.src;
  roundNumber(input.id);
  console.log(input.id);
}

function roundNumber(uInput) {
  var total;
  var element = document.getElementById("roundChoice").value;
  if (element != null) {
    total = element.value;
    document.getElementById("roundChoice").value = "Let's Begin";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("roundChoice").value = "Enter Rounds!!!";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
    var compSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    var winner = document.getElementById("winner");

    if (compSelect === 1) {
      document.getElementById("cpu").src = "images/rock.jpg";
      if (uInput === "rock_1") {
        winner.innerHTML = "you tied!"
        i--;
      } else if (uInput === "paper_1") {
        winner.innerHTML = "User Wins Round" + i + "!"
      } else {
        winner.innerHTML = "Computer Wins Round" + i + "!"
      }
    } else if (compSelect === 2) {
      document.getElementById("cpu").src = "images/paper.jpg";
      if (uInput === "paper_1") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You tied!"
        i--;
      } else if (uInput === "scissors_1") {
        winner.innerHTML("User Wins Round" + i + "!")
      } else {
        winner.innerHTML = "Computer Wins Round" + i + "!"
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cpu").src = "images/scissors.jpg";
      if (uInput === "scissors_1") {
        winner.innerHTML = "You tied!"
        i--;
      } else if (uInput === "rock_1") {
        winner.innerHTML = "User Wins Round" + i + "!"
      } else {
        winner.innerHTML = "computer WIns"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 80% arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  border: solid orange;
  border-width: 0 3px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 78em;
}

#header {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 280% courier;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 8px orange;
}

p.instruct {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  position: relative;
  border: solid orange;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: .5em 0 .5em 0;
}

#startButton {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 2em 2em;
}

#button {
  background: black;
  border: dotted orange;
  color: orange;
  padding: 4px;
}

#clearButton {
  margin: 0 0 0 12em;
}

#newButton {
  background: black;
  border: dotted orange;
  color: orange;
  padding: 4px;
}

#modifiedGame {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}

#newGameBtn {
  background: black;
  border: dotted red;
  color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}

#nameInput {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3em 0 1em 0;
}

#userName {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  border: dotted orange;
  padding: 4px;
}

#submitName {
  margin: 0 0 5em 39em;
}

#rounds {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#roundChoice {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border: dotted orange;
  background: black;
}

#enterRounds {
  margin: 1em 0 2em 39.5em;
}

p.winner {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  /*clear: both;*/
}

::placeholder {
  color: orange;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  color: orange;
}

#images,
p {
  clear: both;
  color: white;
}

#images {
  float: left;
}

#images2 {
  float: right;
}

#cpuNameTag {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0 0 45em;
}

#cpuNameTag2 {
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

#paper_1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#paper_2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#rock_1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#rock_2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#scissors_1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#scissors_2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#rock {
  float: left;
}

#paper {
  float: left;
}

#scissors {
  float: left;
}

#rock2 {
  float: right;
}

#scissors2 {
  float: right;
}

#paper2 {
  float: right;
}

#user_displayed_choice {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#cpu_displayed_choice {
  clear: both;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#displayed_choices {
  margin: 0 31em 0 0;
}

#user {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#cpu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#gameInfo {
  display: none;
}

h4 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="CSS intro" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />

  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <link href="rps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1 id="title"><b>Welcome </b><br><b>to</b> <br><b>Rock Paper Scissors!</b></h1>
    </div>

    <!--Instructions for game-->
    <p class="instruct">Ready to attempt a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors? Select the start button, and then choose the amount of rounds you want to play. Ties in each round will not count towards total rounds. If a tie is present at the end of all the rounds, one final overtime
      round will decide the winner. If you dare, try our harder version by beating the computer to unlock.</p>

    <!--Buttons for Start, Clear, and Harder Game-->
    <div id="modifiedGame">
      <input type="button" id="newGameBtn" onclick="newGame" value="Want to try a harder game?">
    </div>
    <div id="startButton">
      <input type="button" id="button" onclick="startGame()" value="Start Game">
    </div>
    <section id="gameInfo">
      <div id="clearButton">
        <input type="button" id="newButton" onclick="clearGame()" value="Clear Game">
      </div>
      <!--^^^-->

      <!--Name Input, Round Input-->
      <div id="nameInput">
        <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="What is your name?" autofocus required>
      </div>
      <div id="submitName">
        <input type="button" id="nameButton" value="Secure Name" onclick="displayName(this)">
      </div>
      <div id="rounds">
        <input type="text" id="roundChoice" placeholder="Enter # of Rounds" autofocus required>
      </div>
      <div id="enterRounds">
        <input type="button" id="roundButton" value="Set Rounds" onclick="roundNumber(this)">
      </div>

      <div id="cpuNameTag2">
        <h4 id="userDisplay" value=""></h4>
      </div>
      <div id="cpuNameTag">
        <h4>CPU Chooses:</h4>
      </div>

      <!--Clickable Images for User to Choose. Some Displayed by CPU name to show what CPU Chose after User-->
      <div id="images">
        <div id="rock">
          <img src="images/rock.jpg" alt="rock" id="rock_1" onclick="userPick(this)">
        </div>
        <div id="paper">
          <img src="images/paper.jpg" alt="paper" id="paper_1" onclick="userPick(this)">
        </div>
        <div id="scissors">
          <img src="images/scissors.jpg" alt="scissors" id="scissors_1" onclick="userPick(this)">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="images2">
        <div id="scissors2">
          <img src="images/scissors.jpg" alt="scissors" id="scissors_2">
        </div>
        <div id="paper2">
          <img src="images/paper.jpg" alt="paper" id="paper_2">
        </div>
        <div id="rock2">
          <img src="images/rock.jpg" alt="rock" id="rock_2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="displayed_choices">
        <div id="cpu_displayed_choice">
          <img id="cpu" src="">
        </div>
        <div id="user_displayed_choice">
          <img id="user" src="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 id="winner"></h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I looked at your code and is very confusing... you're executing all rounds every time you call `roundNumber()` and you're calling it from the `Set Rounds` button and from the user's rock/paper/scissors images. You should only execute one round per execution. To keep the count of the rounds you can use a global variable (e.g.).

Comment: Yeah, I had switched for that button to activate as i was just messing with things, I forgot to switch it back. Will edit, I had just one function that would register the user selection and send it to the function that will decide the computer choice. I had it set to executing each time I call roundNumber() because i am not sure how I will continue to need the user to select an image before the computer.

Comment: If you show the code with the [code snippet tool](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (or JSFiddle or similar) then it will be easier to test.

Comment: <<  i am not sure how I will continue to need the user to select an image before the computer >> just rely on click events on the rock-paper-scissor images. You don't need to do a loop to execute all the rounds. If you do it event-driven, just react to each user selection.

Comment: Updated with code snippet--------That does make sense, I am pretty used to Java and C++ and having to force the user rather than just go based on the user input.

Comment: With the images broken I don't know where to click to select rock/paper/scissors :(

Comment: And now you're calling `userPick()` with `paper`, but still calling `roundNumber()` with `rock` and `scissors`

Comment: shoot, I didn't think about that. I'm not sure how to include those. This might make it impossible to run for you. Well, dang.

Comment: Ugh, I updated the code in here but not when I did the snippet

Comment: I recommend you to use online pictures, [choose from here](https://www.google.com/search?q=rock+OR+paper+OR+scissors&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:i&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAsauWv7_aAhWDWywKHfHeC3YQpwUIHg&biw=1216&bih=658&dpr=2)

Comment: Do I need to just use the google link or actually go to the images websites? wouldn't this just pull the full link and not the image itself?

Comment: You need to replace the `src` of each imaage with an url of an image.

Comment: I tried that and its still broken and won't display an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example without the `for` loop, using 3 global variables (`currentRound`, `totalRounds` and `wins`).

```js
var currentRound = -1;
var totalRounds = -1;
var wins = -1;
function startGame() {
  document.getElementById("gameInfo").style.display = "contents";
}

function clearGame() {
  document.getElementById("gameInfo").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("cpu").src = "";
  document.getElementById("user").src = "";
  document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("userDisplay").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("userName").value = "";
}

function displayName() {
  var txtName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  document.getElementById("userDisplay").innerHTML = txtName;
}

function setRounds() {
  var value = document.getElementById("roundChoice").value;
  if (value) {
    totalRounds = parseInt(value);
    currentRound = 0;
    wins = 0;
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "Let's Begin";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("roundChoice").value = "Enter Rounds!!!";
    totalRounds = -1;
  }
}

function userPick(input) {
  if (totalRounds < 0) {
    alert("Enter Rounds!!!");
    return;
  }
  
  if (currentRound >= totalRounds) {
    alert("Rounds Finished! Enter Rounds again!!!");
    return;
  }
  //console.log(currentRound + "," + totalRounds)
  document.getElementById("user").src = input.src;
  currentRound++;
  roundNumber(input.id);
}

function roundNumber(uInput) {
  var compSelect = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  var winner = document.getElementById("winner");
  var i = currentRound + 1;
  
  if (compSelect === 1) {
    document.getElementById("cpu").src = "https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/rock-n-roll-gesto-simbolo-de-la-mano-esbozado_318-72191.jpg";
    if (uInput === "rock_1") {
      winner.innerHTML = "you tied!"
      currentRound--;
    } else if (uInput === "paper_1") {
      wins++;
      winner.innerHTML = "User Wins Round " + i + "!"
    } else {
      winner.innerHTML = "Computer Wins Round " + i + "!"
    }
  } else if (compSelect === 2) {
    document.getElementById("cpu").src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/58/78/7c58781da79c7e9b089f206a1ad7b9b5.png";
    if (uInput === "paper_1") {
      winner.innerHTML = "You tied!"
      currentRound--;
    } else if (uInput === "scissors_1") {
      wins++;
      winner.innerHTML = "User Wins Round " + i + "!"
    } else {
      winner.innerHTML = "Computer Wins Round " + i + "!"
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cpu").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/164/164986.png";
    if (uInput === "scissors_1") {
      winner.innerHTML = "You tied!"
      currentRound--;
    } else if (uInput === "rock_1") {
      wins++;
      winner.innerHTML = "User Wins Round " + i + "!"
    } else {
      winner.innerHTML = "computer WIn " + i + "!"
    }  
  }
  
  if (currentRound == totalRounds) {
    alert(totalRounds + " Finished:\n" 
      + "- wins: " + wins + "\n"
      + "- looses: " + (totalRounds - wins))
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 80% arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=button],
#images img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  border: solid orange;
  border-width: 0 3px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 78em;
}

#header {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font: 280% courier;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 8px orange;
}

p.instruct {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  position: relative;
  border: solid orange;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: .5em 0 .5em 0;
}

#startButton {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 2em 2em;
}

#button {
  background: black;
  border: dotted orange;
  color: orange;
  padding: 4px;
}

#clearButton {
  margin: 0 0 0 12em;
}

#newButton {
  background: black;
  border: dotted orange;
  color: orange;
  padding: 4px;
}

#modifiedGame {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}

#newGameBtn {
  background: black;
  border: dotted red;
  color: red;
  padding: 4px;
}

#nameInput {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3em 0 1em 0;
}

#userName {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  border: dotted orange;
  padding: 4px;
}

#submitName {
  margin: 0 0 5em 39em;
}

#rounds {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#roundChoice {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border: dotted orange;
  background: black;
}

#enterRounds {
  margin: 1em 0 2em 39.5em;
}

p.winner {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  /*clear: both;*/
}

::placeholder {
  color: orange;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  color: orange;
}

#images,
p {
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

#images2 {
  float: right;
}

#cpuNameTag {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 0 0 45em;
}

#cpuNameTag2 {
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

#paper_1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#paper_2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#rock_1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#rock_2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#scissors_1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#scissors_2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

#rock {
  float: left;
}

#paper {
  float: left;
}

#scissors {
  float: left;
}

#rock2 {
  float: right;
}

#scissors2 {
  float: right;
}

#paper2 {
  float: right;
}

#user_displayed_choice {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#cpu_displayed_choice {
  clear: both;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#displayed_choices {
  margin: 0 31em 0 0;
}

#user {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#cpu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#gameInfo {
  display: none;
}

h4 {
  color: orange;
}

#winner {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="CSS intro" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />

  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <link href="rps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1 id="title"><b>Welcome </b><br><b>to</b> <br><b>Rock Paper Scissors!</b></h1>
    </div>

    <!--Instructions for game-->
    <p class="instruct">Ready to attempt a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors? Select the start button, and then choose the amount of rounds you want to play. Ties in each round will not count towards total rounds. If a tie is present at the end of all the rounds, one final overtime
      round will decide the winner. If you dare, try our harder version by beating the computer to unlock.</p>

    <!--Buttons for Start, Clear, and Harder Game-->
    <div id="modifiedGame">
      <input type="button" id="newGameBtn" onclick="newGame" value="Want to try a harder game?">
    </div>
    <div id="startButton">
      <input type="button" id="button" onclick="startGame()" value="Start Game">
    </div>
    <section id="gameInfo">
      <div id="clearButton">
        <input type="button" id="newButton" onclick="clearGame()" value="Clear Game">
      </div>
      <!--^^^-->

      <!--Name Input, Round Input-->
      <div id="nameInput">
        <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="What is your name?" autofocus required>
      </div>
      <div id="submitName">
        <input type="button" id="nameButton" value="Secure Name" onclick="displayName(this)">
      </div>
      <div id="rounds">
        <input type="text" id="roundChoice" placeholder="Enter # of Rounds" autofocus required>
      </div>
      <div id="enterRounds">
        <input type="button" id="roundButton" value="Set Rounds" onclick="setRounds()">
      </div>

      <div id="cpuNameTag2">
        <h4 id="userDisplay" value=""></h4>
      </div>
      <div id="cpuNameTag">
        <h4>CPU Chooses:</h4>
      </div>

      <!--Clickable Images for User to Choose. Some Displayed by CPU name to show what CPU Chose after User-->
      <div id="images">
        <div id="rock">
          <img src="https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/rock-n-roll-gesto-simbolo-de-la-mano-esbozado_318-72191.jpg" alt="rock" id="rock_1" onclick="userPick(this)">
        </div>
        <div id="paper">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/58/78/7c58781da79c7e9b089f206a1ad7b9b5.png" alt="paper" id="paper_1" onclick="userPick(this)">
        </div>
        <div id="scissors">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/164/164986.png" alt="scissors" id="scissors_1" onclick="userPick(this)">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="images2">
        <div id="scissors2">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/164/164986.png" alt="scissors" id="scissors_2">
        </div>
        <div id="paper2">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/58/78/7c58781da79c7e9b089f206a1ad7b9b5.png" alt="paper" id="paper_2">
        </div>
        <div id="rock2">
          <img src="https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/rock-n-roll-gesto-simbolo-de-la-mano-esbozado_318-72191.jpg" alt="rock" id="rock_2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="displayed_choices">
        <div id="cpu_displayed_choice">
          <img id="cpu" src="">
        </div>
        <div id="user_displayed_choice">
          <img id="user" src="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 id="winner"></h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This helps a ton. It laid out what i am, for the most part, trying to achieve. Thank you a ton, there are a few things I want to tweek and change up, but this is what I was wanting to know.